Plot legend isn't displaying the color of the individual lines
The following is not the use case I actually need, but it serves as a perfectly fine example. When I try to run the following code I get the legend, but the legend appears without the corresponding colors of the lines. I am running matplotlib version 3.8.3.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 1000)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

plt.plot(x, y1, "-b", label="sine")
plt.plot(x, y2, "-r", label="cosine")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.ylim(-1.5, 2.0)
plt.show()


Using plt.scatter works fine. Adding colors to the plot command does not.

With matplotlib 3.9.2 all works as expected... maybe consider updating to the most recent version
